# where can we host privacy policy and its link?

Tags: android, privacy, policy

Can privacy policy just a paragraph ? Can we put our privacy policy text in facebook page and privide link to it in developer console?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. (It's also potentially asking for legal advice, depending on the jurisdiction where the poster resides, and this is not a legal advice site.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do make `google blog` and `blog url` add in to `privacy policy` field update

Comment: do you mean blogger.com?

Comment: yes.. i have also create blog and add url in privacy policy field

Comment: can you give me your link?

Comment: bro last question. I got the date in permalink. How can I remove that.